# Trouble installing h5py on OS X 10.14.6 (Mojave)

Tags: python, python3

I am trying to install the H5py (`h5py`) Python wrapper for the HDF5 library (https://pypi.org/project/h5py/) in a virtual env. on my MacBook Air (mid 2019) running OS X 10.14.6 (Mojave). The Python version is 3.7.4.

For reference, I used the H5py build instructions page https://h5py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/build.html.

As `h5py` requires MPICH (http://www.mpich.org) and the HDF5 (https://www.hdfgroup.org/solutions/hdf5/) system libraries, I installed these via Brew, and then installed `h5py` using a fork of the Git repository (https://github.com/h5py/h5py).

These are the steps I followed in the given order.

```
1. brew install mpich && pip install mpi4py

2. brew install hdf5

3. git clone https://github.com/mygit/h5py

4. cd h5py && python setup.py configure --mpi

5. python setup.py configure --hdf5=/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5

6. pip setup.py install
```

Everything seemed to be fine with the last step (`h5py` install).

```
...
Using /path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Finished processing dependencies for h5py==2.10.0

```
$ pip freeze | grep h5py
h5py==2.10.0
```

But I am unable to import `h5py` in Python 3.

```
In [1]: import h5py                                                                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c9f0b8c65221> in <module>
----> 1 import h5py

/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py-2.10.0-py3.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/h5py/__init__.py in <module>
     32         raise
     33 
---> 34 from . import version
     35 
     36 if version.hdf5_version_tuple != version.hdf5_built_version_tuple:

/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py-2.10.0-py3.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/h5py/version.py in <module>
     15 
     16 from collections import namedtuple
---> 17 from . import h5 as _h5
     18 import sys
     19 import numpy

h5py/h5.pyx in init h5py.h5()

ImportError: dlopen(/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py-2.10.0-py3.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/h5py/defs.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _H5Fget_mpi_atomicity
  Referenced from: /path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py-2.10.0-py3.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/h5py/defs.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py-2.10.0-py3.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/h5py/defs.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Can someone please explain what the problem is here?